# how combine '"+variable+"' in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I should get variable printed like this
'"value"'
in this case value would be value from variable a.

How to do this properly?

```
 a=b

 SUCCESS= ''"'+a+' "' '
```

Comment: `SUCCESS= '"' +a+ '"'` -- you miscounted the number of single quotes. Better use an editor that can syntax highlight strings.

Comment: Thank from reply. I meant that the print(SUCCESS) should produce this kind of string

' "b" '

Comment: I don't think Python can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sucess="'"+'"'+str(a)+'"'+"'"
```

Comment: @Auvite: Really? That worked? So you got `"b"`,  the result that you were after, according to your comment?